# How can parent process tell child to do something when something happens to parent?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, fork, pipe

I need help in making a parent and child process talk to each other while serving as `fork()`'d parts of a TCP server program. Let's call the parent A of the TCP server and the child, B. A receives data from the Client and B sends data to that client automatically. When A receives "hi", B should say "hello". The problem is, `pipe()` doesn't seem to work and A needs to tell B that the Client has sent something that requires reply. I've read about shared memory but it doesn't seem to be practical for my use.

Please suggest some ways on how can I implement this. I am able to send user-prompted messages from both ends of the TCP socket and I can't get the client to reply automatically.

For some reasons I cannot make a full disclosure of the whole code. Here are some:

Main:

```
int fd[2];
char bufout[10];
char bufin[10];
if (pipe2(fd,O_NONBLOCK) < 0) puts("Warning: Pipes not Running");

int id = fork();
if (id == -1) {
    perror("fork: ");
    return 1;
}
```

Parent:

```
printf("Client %s connected. \n",cli_ip);     
        while(1){
            memset(mesg,0,sizeof(mesg));
            if( recvfrom(connfd,mesg,sizeof(mesg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len) > 0 ){

                    printf("From %s port %d: %s",cli_ip,ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port),mesg);
                    if (strncmp(mesg,"hi",4) == 0) {
                        printf("%s hi you\n",cli_ip);
                        close(fd[0]);
                        write(fd[1],"hi",sizeof("hi"));

                    }
            }
            else {
                    printf("Client %s disconnected. \n",cli_ip);      
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Child:

```
while (1){
        close(fd[1]);
        if (read(fd[0],bufin,sizeof(bufin))) sendto(sockfd,"hello\r",strlen("hello\r"),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,len);

        strcpy(bufin,"");

    }
```

Well, the "Pipe not Running" message does not show up, that's a given. And I feel it's because some thing’s blocked along the way.

Comment: please post some code to understand why pipe() doesnt work

Comment: also http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html

Comment: To start with, you're closing the pipes filedescriptors in loops. Close them _once_ only. Secondly, you don't check if `read` in the child actually _reads_ anything, what if it returns `-1`? That is also "not false". Also, what is the definition of `bufin`?

Comment: Face it. Children do not always listen to parents. Its up to the parents to make sure they do. :) :)

Comment: A third point, instead of just saying "it doesn't seem work", maybe you can explain _how_ it doesn't work with pipes? What happens?

Comment: Why do some people not seem to care about how the 'papers' look they are showing to the world. The source is badly formatted.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just let the child handle the recv and the send? It is typical on unix systems to have a listener process spawn/fork children who then receive and respond to messages, while the parent keeps on listening for new connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a basic UDP based message-passing mechanism in C(make sure it runs in a separate thread). That time, when something happens to A, B can be notified by a datagram. Likewise with B.

Comment: Actually, this is a preparation for a more heavy use of TCP sockets (which I cannot disclose) and I can't move ahead when there's this difficulty I'm having.

Comment: If you want to communicate between two processes - anywhere on your local area network, then you can use the Datagram packet(UDP) effectively and efficiently. This will be way faster than TCP for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can create loopback sockets and use them for IPC.
[Here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node28.html) is a good reference.

Comment: It will work. But is there a faster way to implement this without having to bind addresses or having to use socket types other than stream? If I implement a stream socket, it will take up time and the time limit is two seconds.

Comment: Under Unix, socketpair() is a handy function for this.